# Abrir nova pagina automaticamente em php com resultado da pagina anterior

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Seguinte pessoal tenho um questionário e no fim um button submit, ao clicar eu faço algumas operações php para retornar um resultado do questionário, mas retorna na mesma página, com todas as perguntas do questionário, eu preciso retornar esse resultado ou em uma nova página, ou quando clicar o button as perguntas desaparecessem e ficasse somente o resultado, alguém que consiga me ajudar? esse é o botão e o código php que estou usando para dar o resultado...

```
<button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Enviar</button>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

        foreach ($_POST['question'] as $key => $value) {
            $letter[$key] = array_sum($value);
        }
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">Letra com maior valor: '.array_search(max($letter),$letter).'</div>'; 
        if (array_search(max($letter),$letter) == "A" ){
            echo 'Lorem';
        }
        if (array_search(max($letter),$letter) == "B" ){
            echo 'Lorem ipsum';
        }
        if (array_search(max($letter),$letter) == "C" ){
            echo 'Lorem ipsum lorem';
        }
    }

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No formulario da sua pesquisa você precisa definir a propriedade "**action**" com o endereço da pagina destino, ex:

```
<form action="/resultado.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="question"...>
  <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Comment: obrigado vou tentar aqui ja retorno